# How to design T-SQL query to calculate sum in one pass?

Tags: t-sql

I am trying to develop a T-SQL query which will do the following:

```
ROUND(100 * A / B, 1)
```

Simple in concept, but it's tricky because of possible B=0 denominator and also because of A and B variables.  What I expect is a percent value like 93.2 (given in this format without %).  Or even 932 would be acceptable since I could convert it later.

But instead, I'm currently getting 151, which is the number of records.

```
A = CASE WHEN A.MFG IS NULL AND A.MFG2 IS NULL AND A.QC IS NULL AND A.QC2 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
B = CASE WHEN [Date_Completed] IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

My current logic only divides A/B if B is not equal to zero.  Can you please help me fix this?  p.s. all fields above are from the same table A.

I tried:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN t.VarB<>0 THEN ROUND(100 * t.VarA / t.VarB, 1) 
ELSE 0 /* or whatever you'd want to return in this case */ 
END 
FROM (SELECT CASE WHEN A.MFG IS NULL AND A.MFG2 IS NULL AND A.QC IS NULL AND A.QC2 IS NULL THEN 1 
ELSE 0 
END AS VarA, 
CASE WHEN [Date_Completed] IS NOT NULL THEN 1 
ELSE 0 
END AS VarB 
FROM EXCEL.Batch_Records A) t
```

But I got 33000 rows returned instead of just one, where each row = 100 or 0.

Good idea, Conrad! I tested your solution and it works if I just want that one value.  But what I didn't tell you was that there are additional values I need returned from same query.  When I tried adding in the other value calculations, I got syntax errors.  So here is my current query.  How should htis be rewritten please?

```
select 
SUM(CASE WHEN A.DATE_RECEIVED IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NUM_RECEIVED,
SUM(CASE WHEN [Date_Completed] IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NUM_COMPLETE_OF_OPENED,
SUM(CASE WHEN A.DATE_COMPLETED IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NUM_COMPLETED_IN_MONTH,
SUM(CASE WHEN A.MFG IS NULL AND A.MFG2 IS NULL AND A.QC IS NULL AND A.QC2 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NUM_WITHOUT_ERROR,

round(100 * a/b , 1) 
from 
(select 
    sum(CASE  
        WHEN A.MFG IS NULL AND A.MFG2 IS NULL AND A.QC IS NULL AND A.QC2 IS NULL THEN  
            1.0  
        ELSE 0.0 END) A, 
    sum(CASE WHEN [Date_Completed] IS NOT NULL THEN 

1.0 ELSE 0.0 END) B 

FROM EXCEL.Batch_Records a 
LEFT JOIN EXCEL.QC_CODES d ON a.Part_Number = d.CODE_ID    
WHERE (a.[Group] = @GROUP or @GROUP = '' OR @GROUP IS NULL) AND A.Date_Received >= @STARTDATE AND A.Date_Received <= @ENDDATE
```

Conrad correctly advised me that #TEMP1 was an empty table.  But now I populated it and successfully designed this query with his help:

```
SET @STARTDATE = '1/1/11'
SET @ENDDATE = '1/31/11'
SET @GROUP = 'INTERMEDIATES_FISH'
--SET @TABLE_TITLE = 'BATCH RECORD SUCCESS RATE'
--SET @DEPT = 'QC'     

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM TEMPDB.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '#TEMP1%')
DROP TABLE #TEMP1

--CREATE TABLE #TEMP1 (     MFG int ,      MFG2 int ,     QC int,      QC2 INT ,      [Group] NVARCHAR(MAX),     [Date_Completed] datetime,     Date_Received datetime)
SELECT
MFG, MFG2, QC, QC2, [GROUP], [DATE_COMPLETED], [DATE_RECEIVED]
INTO #TEMP1
FROM EXCEL.Batch_Records a 
WHERE (a.[Group] = @GROUP or @GROUP = '' OR @GROUP IS NULL) AND A.Date_Received >= @STARTDATE AND A.Date_Received <= @ENDDATE

------------------------------------------  
;WITH CTE AS 
( 
SELECT 
CASE 
WHEN A.MFG IS NULL AND A.MFG2 IS NULL AND A.QC IS NULL AND A.QC2 IS NULL THEN 
1.0 
ELSE 0.0 END A, 
CASE WHEN [Date_Completed] IS NOT NULL THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END B, 
CASE WHEN A.Date_Received IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END NUM_RECEIVED, 
CASE WHEN [Date_Completed] IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END NUM_COMPLETE_OF_OPENED, 
CASE WHEN A.DATE_COMPLETED IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END NUM_COMPLETED_IN_MONTH, 
CASE WHEN A.MFG IS NULL AND A.MFG2 IS NULL AND A.QC IS NULL AND A.QC2 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS NUM_WITHOUT_ERROR 
FROM 
#TEMP1 a 
--WHERE (a.[Group] = @GROUP or @GROUP = '' OR @GROUP IS NULL) AND A.Date_Received >= @STARTDATE AND A.Date_Received <= @ENDDATE
) 

select 
round(100 * SUM(A)/SUM(b) , 1) , 
SUM(NUM_RECEIVED) NUM_RECEIVED, 
SUM(NUM_COMPLETE_OF_OPENED) NUM_COMPLETE_OF_OPENED, 
SUM(NUM_COMPLETED_IN_MONTH) NUM_COMPLETED_IN_MONTH, 
SUM(NUM_WITHOUT_ERROR) NUM_WITHOUT_ERROR 


FROM CTE
```

Comment: Could you add the table schema?  If t.VarA and t.VarB are of data type INT, it will return INT (never giving you a decimal).

Question: are you looking to summarize and return only 1 row or should each row have the percentage calculation performed against it?

Comment: Well you have two From clauses so that's not looking good... Try this put in a few rows of data from Batch_Records and QC_CODES. Then put it what your output should look like.

Comment: just 1 row total (summarize).  MFG, MFG2, QC, QC2, Group are all NVARCHAR(MAX) in database.  Date_completed is datetime.  Does that answer ur questions?

Comment: @Conrad, I just copied the two FROM statements from your answer below.  Did I misunderstand you?  And I'm not sure what you mean about few rows of data.  Do you mean that you want to see what these values look like or that I need to populate data?

Comment: @salvationishere If you look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758808/how-can-i-write-this-query-as-a-full-join-instead-of-a-union-left-right-join). Eric H. Provides a script to create a temp table and inserts for the test data. He also then includes the expected output. This makes it easier for people to help.

Comment: Yes, I got that.  Initially I did create his temp table and tested and it did what I expected.  But my whole point in not creating a temp table for the solution is because I'm trying to improve performance and speed.  Otherwise, I could easily calculate this in two passes.  Make sense?  All I need to know is how to add this field output into existing outputs as described below.

Comment: @salvationishere the purpose of the temp table is to deal with  the fact that we don't share the DB, not a performance thing. That said I took my best guess at what you're trying to do

Comment: @salvationishere all nulls means that either #temp1 has no records or the where clause is filtering them all out. Can you provide INSERT INTO Statements

Comment: I'm loving it!  You were correct; I was filtering them out.  But I fixed it now and now I get exactly what I wanted!  Thank you so much, Conrad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to use SUM() to get the sum. You should also use 1.0 and 0.0 so you get decimal values.

You should also do the SUM before the Division

**UPDATE** 
Since you're adding in a number of `SUM(CASE` statements its probably more readable to move the CASE statments out to a CTE.

```
CREATE TABLE #Batch_Records (
    MFG int , 
    MFG2 int ,
    QC int, 
    QC2 INT , 
    [Group] int,
    [Date_Completed] datetime,
    Date_Received datetime)




INSERT INTO #Batch_Records (MFG ,   MFG2 ,  QC ,    QC2  ,  [Group] ,   [Date_Completed] ,  Date_Received )
VALUES (1,null,null,null,1,'1/4/2011','2/4/2011'),
       (null,null,null,null,1,'2/2/2011','3/4/2011'),
       (1,null,null,null,1,'3/6/2011','4/3/2011'),
       (null,null,null,null,1,NULL,'5/4/2011'),
       (1,null,null,null,1,'5/4/2011','6/6/2011'),
       (1,null,null,null,1,NULL,'7/4/2011')


DECLARE @GROUP int
DECLARE @STARTDATE DateTime
DECLARE @ENDDATE DateTime

SET @GROUP = 1
SET @STARTDATE = '1/1/2001'
SET @ENDDATE = '1/1/2012'

;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT
        CASE  
            WHEN A.MFG IS NULL AND A.MFG2 IS NULL AND A.QC IS NULL AND A.QC2 IS NULL THEN  
                1.0  
            ELSE 0.0 END A, 
        CASE WHEN [Date_Completed] IS NOT NULL THEN 
        1.0 ELSE 0.0 END B,
        CASE WHEN A.Date_Received IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  NUM_RECEIVED,
        CASE WHEN [Date_Completed] IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  NUM_COMPLETE_OF_OPENED,   
        CASE WHEN A.DATE_COMPLETED IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  NUM_COMPLETED_IN_MONTH,
        CASE WHEN A.MFG IS NULL AND A.MFG2 IS NULL AND A.QC IS NULL AND A.QC2 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS NUM_WITHOUT_ERROR
    FROM 
        #Batch_Records a 
    WHERE 
        (a.[Group] = @GROUP or @GROUP = '' OR @GROUP IS NULL) 
        AND A.Date_Received >= @STARTDATE AND A.Date_Received <= @ENDDATE
)

select 
    round(100 * SUM(A)/SUM(b) , 1) ,
    SUM(NUM_RECEIVED) NUM_RECEIVED,
    SUM(NUM_COMPLETE_OF_OPENED) NUM_COMPLETE_OF_OPENED,
    SUM(NUM_COMPLETED_IN_MONTH) NUM_COMPLETED_IN_MONTH,
    SUM(NUM_WITHOUT_ERROR) NUM_WITHOUT_ERROR


 FROM CTE

 DROP TABLE #Batch_Records
```

Comment: Good point about the decimal values though.  But can u have another look?  I'm updating my problem.

Comment: Conrad, could you please have a look at my comment above in response to your comment?

Comment: I'm sorry Conrad, but could you have just one more look at my query?  It's returning all NULL values even though I copied your code.

Comment: @salvationishere Can you update your question with the SQL that you used. If you run exactly what I wrote it will return `50.000000 6 4 4 2`

Comment: I ran almost exactly what you wrote and it still returns all NULLs.  FYI, all of these variables are VARCHARs, not INTs.  So I am adding now the SQL that I used.